# how to figure out which bank a customer card belongs to when using square

Tags: square

We are saving client cards on file to charge them at a later date.
We are getting a lot of declines and would like to know which banks are declining our payments.
Is there anyway to easily see this info?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

All the data about the issuing institution is encoded in the credit card number itself.

https://www.creditcardinsider.com/learn/anatomy-of-a-credit-card/

https://chargebacks911.com/bank-identification-numbers/

Basically, the first six digits encode the type of card, and the issuing institution. This should give you enough to get on with.